# Xamarin Forms - Check a switch has been toggled manually

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am writing a Xamarin forms application which checks whether or not a user is in a specific geo-location. When a user walks inside an area, a `XAML` switch is toggled from the off to on position.

```
farmSwitch.toggled = true;
```

This calls this function

```
farmSwitch.Toggled += (object sender, ToggledEventArgs e) => {
            manualOnFarm = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Switch.Toggled event sent");
            changeOnFarmStatus(e);
        };
```

I also need functionality where a user **manually** clicks the switch, which need to be differentiated from when the code automatically toggles `farmSwitch`

The reason is that I have a boolean that should only be true when the user manually clicks `farmSwitch`, and should be false when the switch is toggled automatically

What are my options? Ideally there would be a farSwtich.clicked() function I could call for when a user manually clicks `farmSwitch`, but no such luck

Comment: You should use data binding, it's easier to work with data. Otherwise, you should get the value from e.Value in your call function

Comment: Switch has just toggle whether manually or programmatically, if you want differentiation keep two one visible and another invisible. Or keep a property named IsProgrammmatically set it true if you do it from code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how you can't just differentiate between this by using some kind of marker in the code you've written that programatically toggles the switch?

So you call this programatically but you also set a boolean marker to say this is a programatic change:

```
private bool HasBeenProgrammaticallyToggled = false;

public void ThisIsAProgrammaticToggle()
{
      HasBeenProgrammaticallyToggled = true;
      farmSwitch.toggled = true;
}
```

and in your little on toggled event just do:

```
farmSwitch.Toggled += (object sender, ToggledEventArgs e) => {
            if(HasBeenProgrammaticallyToggled)
            {
                 //This has been toggled programmatically, so reset our bool
                 HasBeenProgrammaticallyToggled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                 // I am assuming this is what you use to determine a manual toggle?
                 manualOnFarm = true;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Switch.Toggled event sent");
            changeOnFarmStatus(e);
        };
```

Wouldn't this work?

Comment: You're right, thanks! I was just hoping there would be a cleaner way to do it I suppose. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

Use @digitalsa1nt 's suggestion or, use "-=" the method before you switch it manually and use "+=" again.